# QML - How to modify MouseArea onPressed and onReleased in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, qml

I know that I can connect onClicked event like this:

```
myMouseAreaID.clicked.connect(someJavaScriptFunction)
```

But I am unable to find anything similar for events onPressed and onReleased...

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myMouseArea.released.connect(fun)` works as expected, but the `pressed` signal is shadowed by a [Boolean property with the same name](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-mousearea.html#pressed-prop) indicating whether a button is currently pressed. Therefore it is currently impossible to connect this signal dynamically.

This is actually a known bug, see [QTBUG-24477](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-24477). All you can do right now is to redesign your application that way it won't depend on that particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have found workaround in meantime:

```
MouseArea
{
    id: ma
    signal onPressedState
    onPressed: onPressedState()
}
```

so later in JavaScript it can be used like this:

```
function someFunction()
{
    ma.onPressedState.connect(someOtherFunction)
}
```

This works :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the more declarative `Connections` type to handle the press:

```
Connections {
    target: myMouseAreaID
    onPressed: myPressedFunc()
}
```

Comment: That is good way, but I needed to be done in JavaScript. I solved it using workaround which I presented in my answer below.